# Showing content on home page but not for all pages

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

i'm using cakephp 1.3 and I want to make my slide of pictures to be displayed only in my home page.
i'm useing the following code:

```
<?php
    if($page == 'home'){
?>
   //The content of slider here
<?php 
}else{
?>
 the message that the slider is only avaliable on homepage... or blank
<?php
 }
?>
```

In the "home" it works fine, but when i go the other controller page such as my "girls" controller it displays this message:

```
Undefined variable: page [APP\views\elements\header_layout.ctp, line 38]
```

can somebody help here?

Answer (score 1):

Change your initial if() to

```
if (isset($page) && ($page == 'home')) {
    ...
}
```

That'll remove the warning.